# How can I call random pictures from a specific file in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

I am designing an experiment. I need to create 3 arrays and combine them together with

```
 itertools.product(a,b,c)
```

I did it while using texts instead of images. While using images, I need to write whole windows paths of the images but I want to avoid it since there are too many.

Is there some sort of code that can create an array that (for example, array named "a") contains all my images so I can combine them with itertools.

Expected output:

```
a = ("a list that contains all images from file A")
b = ("a list that contains all images from file B")
c = ("stimuliA", "StimuliB")
```

so I can create a total combination of these with:

```
itertools.product(a,b,c)
```

Comment: You said about `creating an array that contains all your images`. What should the list contain, the file names?

Comment: paths of the files so I can use them with expyriment package (package needs paths to use images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) for this purpose like below:

```
import os
import glob


def get_images(folder_name, extensions=['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg']):
    dir_path = os.getcwd()
    image_files = []
    for extension in extensions:
         image_files.extend(glob.glob("{}\*.{}".format(folder_name, extension))) 
    return list(map(lambda filename: dir_path +"\\"+ filename, image_files))

a = get_images("A") 
b = get_images("B")
c = get_images("C")
```

I've written a  function `get_images`. There are two parameters `folder_name` and `extensions` (optional argument)

By default, we will be searching for `jpg, png, jpeg` extensions in the specified folder. `dir_path` contains the current directory path. `glob` lists all the files with the specified extension.

After getting all the relative paths of the images of different extensions we merge them all together into a list named `image_files`.

Finally, we concatenate each of them with the `dir_path` to create an absolute path of each image using the [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) expression.